# Install XAP file locally in windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, xap, appx, windows-dev-center

Hope You are doing well.

Actually i have created one windows phone 8 application. So for testing i have installed the **.xap** file locally into windows phone 8 and it is working fine. But if i am going to install that **.xap** package in windows phone 8.1 or later it is not getting installed.

I have made research and found that the windows phone 8.1 and later OS version devices are accepting the **APPX** Package. They will not allow to install **.XAP** locally. Now the scenario is like that my client wants to test this application in windows phone 8.1 device.

So, **Can anyone help me out that how can we install locally XAP package into windows phone 8.1 device?**

Awaiting Response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the phone in question developer unlocked?

Comment: yes it is developer unlocked

Comment: use this tool to deploy the xap: https://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you have windows phone developer account ? @ChandniSirwani

Comment: If yes then store can provide app visiblity by it's microsoft account login in windows phone. @ChandniSirwani

Comment: yes i have and i got it @KrunalMevada

Answer (score 2):

You can sideload your .xap package on Windows Phone 8.1 device using  [**Windows Phone Application Deployment Tool**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632395.aspx#Deploying%20an%20app%20with%20the%20Application%20Deployment%20tool) (for 8.1).

Before installing , you need to ensure the device has been registered for development. You can use [**Windows Phone Developer Registration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx) (8.1) to enable your device for development.

And you could search for the tool from the Windows 8.1 start menu.

Comment: This feature is only available on developer's end. But the client can't do that as they haven't this windows phone application deployment tool.

Comment: You may ask the client to install the necessary [SDK tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402523(v=vs.105).aspx) and Visual Studio. There seems no other distribution way unless you upload it to the Store with hidden availability. Make your client get the app with direct url or promo code.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT Thanks for the update. I have one query like if we will publish it with set as hidden and we will pass that url to client. Then after can we make it for public ? I mean no hidden after that .

Comment: Yes. Just create a new submission and change the **Distribution and visibility** option to **make this app available in the Store**, then your app will be available to public.

Comment: Thanks :) @MattewWu-MSFT